# Nginx location to FLASK route

Tags: nginx, flask

I have 2 docker containers running. 1 is FLASK and 2 is Nginx.
This is the configuration of the Nginx location

```
location /search/?(.*) {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8080/search/;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    }
```

The FLASK is running on port 8080 and the route `@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])` and running with `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'mydomain.com'`

When I try to send a GET request to "mydomain.com" (going through the NGINX) from external I get

> Cannot GET /search

When I remove `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'mydomain.com'` from the FLASK I can send GET to `EXTERNAL_IP:8080` (Directly to the backend not though the NGINX).

But when I leave the `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'mydomain.com'` and try to GET `mydomain.com:8080` I get `404 Not Found`

What am I missing here?

I want all requests to go though the NGINX and I want to use **mydomain.com**

Comment: I'm not familiar with flask, my following questions will be about your app, since your nginx config looks really weird. What kind of routes you app expects? Should it be `/search/some/path` or `/search?args` or `/search/?args` or `/search/some/path?args`? Or the parameters should be passed as a POST request body? Why do you put those `proxy_http_version 1.1;`, `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` and `proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';` lines into your config? They need to be used if you want to proxy a WebSocket connection; is it really your case?

Comment: I guess I really don't need these extras. My app is expecting `mydomain/search?args`. And you are right, the issue is in the app. because when using `EXTERNAL_IP:8080/search?args` and not setting any `SERVER_NAME` in the app it's working. But when using the `SERVER_NAME` it's returning 404.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main mistake is that you trying to match the whole request URI including the query part while `location` directive (as well as the `rewrite` one) works with the **normalized** URI which doesn't include the query part at all (check the `location` directive [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/location) to find out what URI normalization is). Looks like you are also trying to use a regex while regex location should be declared using a `~` (or `~*`) modifier. Nevertheless you don't need any regex locations at all for your particular case. To proxy a single API endpoint preservig the `Host` HTTP header value, you can try this one:

```
location = /search {
    proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

You don't need to specify an URI with the `proxy_pass` directive since you are not changing your request URI. If your API endpoint is `/search/` rather than `/search`, change the location accordingly. If it is an URI path prefix rather than a single API endpoint, use a prefix `location /search/ { ... }` instead of exact match location.